# Set imageview to fit any device in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I have an imageview in Android that I want to horizontally fit and stay in one place in all devices (regardless of size)

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

the image is `1280px` and I am placing it at the bottom of the screen. But if the app is opened in a tablet then image is moved to left and there is a huge empty space on the right side. I tried `fitxy` but image got distorted. I don't want to set the image as background.

How can I make sure when the app is opened in a tablet, the image is still centered with no empty space on right or left side?

Comment: Instead of android:src, try using android:background.

Comment: did you try android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `android:layout_weight="1"` in `LinearLayout` for your `ImageView`.

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

of course this is better to use when you have another view in layout and don't want to be covered by your image.

Answer (score 0):

You have an ImageView and the source of the image view is your image; Since your ImageView you have the attributes

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Then The size of your ImageView will be "equal" to the size of the image because it's wrapping it. What you have to do is specify the size of the image view regardless the size of the image using for example

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```